# PHP str_replace have different value each time?

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to do a str_replace for a HTML String, everytime find a match item the value will increase as well.

```
$link = 1;

$html = str_replace($this->link, $link, $html);
```

This would replace all in once, and with same string $link, i would like the $link increase every time it found an match. is it possible?

Thanks very much

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php and increment the counter in your callback function.

Comment: Agree with dan.  Then simply count how many matches found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (you want each match replaced with growing integer), it would seem the comments on the question encouraging you to use `preg_replace_callback` would be correct:

```
$str = 'Hello World';
$cnt = 0;

function myCallback ( $matches ) {
  global $cnt;
  return ++$cnt;
}

// He12o Wor3d
echo preg_replace_callback( '/\l/', 'myCallback', $str );
```

Comment: this myCallback, what if its in a Class? 
echo preg_replace_callback( '/\l/', $this->myCallback, $str ); doesn't work

Comment: `preg_replace_callback( '/\l/', array($this, 'myCallback'), $text);`

Comment: preg_replace_callback( '/\l/', 'self::myCallback', $text); this works as well

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to return how many replacements it does.

```
<?php
$string = "red green green blue red";

preg_replace('/\b(green)\b/i', '[removed]', $string, -1 , $results);
echo $results; // returns '2' as it replaces green twice with [removed]
?>
```